# Python - How to Implement Probabilistic Neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network

I want to apply Probabilistic Neural Network. My `data.csv` file contains values in first column. The values are float values. I have encountered the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "G:/Setups/Python/pnn-1.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       input_dataset_target = genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skip_header=0, usecols=(TARGET_COLUMN-1))   File
>   "G:\Setups\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1769, in
>   genfromtxt
>       raise ValueError(errmsg)

The code I have performed:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
from neupy.algorithms import PNN

filename = "data.csv"
TARGET_COLUMN = 2

from numpy import genfromtxt
input_dataset_data = 
genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=',',skip_header=0,usecols=
(range(0,TARGET_COLUMN-1)))
input_dataset_target = genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skip_header=0, 
usecols=(TARGET_COLUMN-1))

kfold_number = 2

skfold = StratifiedKFOld(input_dataset_target, kfold_number, shuffle=True)
average_result = 0

print("> Start classify input_dataset dataset")

for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skfold, start=1):

pnn_network = PNN(std=0.1, step=0.2, verbose=True)

pnn_network.train(input_dataset_data[train], input_dataset_target[train])
predictions = pnn_network.predict(input_dataset_data[test])

print(predictions)
#print(input_dataset_target[test])

mcc = matthews_corrcoef(input_dataset_target[test], predictions)
print ("The Matthews correlation coefficient is %f" % mcc)

print("kfold #{:<2}: Guessed {} out of {}".format(
    i, np.sum(predictions == input_dataset_target[test]), test.size
    ))
```

Comment: can you show full error message? you show a traceback but not the error message itself.